# Why Isn't This Form Auto-Submitting Upon File Select?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, upload

Below is the code of the page, however, you will see in the head that I have put in javascript that is supposed to check to see if there is a file selected via the file upload input field located at the bottom of the code.  After it detects the file selection, then it is supposed to automatically submit the form, but for some reason it is not submitting automatically.  Why isn't this working?  Thanks in advance!

**JavaScript: (in `head`)**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("photofield").onchange = function() {
            document.getElementById("form").submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

**HTML (Form):**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="photoupload.php" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="524288">
    <p><input id="photofield" type="file" name="upload" /></p>
    </fieldset>
    <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("form").trigger('submit');` instead of `document.getElementById("form").submit();`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have an input element (`submit button`) with name `submit` and this is the problem, if you change the name of the submit button to something else than `submit` then it'll work, for example, change your submit button code to `btn_submit` instead of `submit`

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit" />
```

Now try this

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("photofield").onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    };
};
```

With the name `submit`, it throws the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function
```

it sets a property `submit` to the `HTMLFormElement`, so the method `submit` in the `prototype` of the form element can't be executed, check [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7dHcb/) (tested in Chrome only).

Also, it's important to register the event on window [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) (also read [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) and read [this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded) too) event because the form is not available when your code runs in the `head` section and it'll throw following error

```
Cannot set property 'onchange' of null
```